# How to get the values of the inner array in react axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios

There is no problem in the renderQuestions part. It prints the first question. The problem is at the renderChoices part. What I need is printing the first questions 4 choice(a.)1970 b.) 1971 c.)1972 d.)1973). Now it prints the numbers between 0 and 3.

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";

class QuizApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { questions: [], choices: [] };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get("http://private-anon-c06008d89c-quizmasters.apiary-mock.com/questions")
      .then(response => {
        const allQuestions = [];
        const allChoices = [];

        response.data.forEach(({ question, choices }) => {
          allQuestions.push(question);
          allChoices.push(choices);
        });
        this.setState({ questions: allQuestions, choices: allChoices });
      });
  }

  renderQuestions = () => {
    let data = [];

    this.state.questions.map((que, i) => {
      data.push(<li key={i}>{que}</li>);
    });
    return data[0];
  };
  renderChoices = () => {
    let data = [];

    Object.keys(this.state.choices).map((ch, i) => {
      Object.keys(this.state.choices[ch]).map((cc, ii) => {
        data.push(<li key={ii}>{cc}</li>);
      });
    });
    return data;
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.renderQuestions()}
        {this.renderChoices()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the structure of a choice object.

Comment: It does look like this  "question": "When the C programming language has first appeared?",
        "choices": [
            {
                "choice": "1970",
                "correct": false
            }, {
                "choice": "1971",
                "correct": false
            }, {
                "choice": "1972",
                "correct": true
            }, {
                "choice": "1973",
                "correct": false
            }
        ]
    },

Comment: do you want to show only first question or all questions and choices ?

Comment: first question and their choices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I see why you'd want to render all questions, then all choices. I assume this is just a test?

Given the existing structure of the data, a better solution is to map one question (and its solutions) to a Component.

Like this:

```js
function Question (props) {
  return (
    <div className="Question">
      <h4>{props.question}</h4>
      <ul>
        {props.choices.map((c, i) => (
          <li className={c.correct && "correct"} key={i}>
            {c.choice}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

class QuizApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { questions: [] };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get(
        "https://private-anon-c06008d89c-quizmasters.apiary-mock.com/questions"
      )
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({ questions: response.data });
      });
  }

  render() {
    return <div>{this.state.questions.map(q => new Question(q))}</div>;
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<QuizApp />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```css
#app .Question li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0.5em;
}

#app .Question .correct {
  background-color: lime;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.18.0/axios.min.js"></script>
```

You can now easily modify this to show just one question at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You need map through data array, not returning it:

```
        import React from "react";
        import axios from "axios";

        class QuizApp extends React.Component {
          constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = { questions: [], choices: [] };
          }

          componentDidMount() {
            axios
              .get("http://private-anon-c06008d89c-quizmasters.apiary-mock.com/questions")
              .then(response => {
                const allQuestions = [];
                const allChoices = [];

                response.data.forEach(({ question, choices }) => {
                  allQuestions.push(question);
                  allChoices.push(choices);
                });
                this.setState({ questions: allQuestions, choices: allChoices });
              });
          }

          renderQuestions = () => {
            let data = [];

            this.state.questions.map((que, i) => {
              data.push(<li key={i}>{que}</li>);
            });
            return data[0];
          };
          renderChoices = () => {
            let data = [];

            Object.keys(this.state.choices).map((ch, i) => {
              Object.keys(this.state.choices[ch]).map((cc, ii) => {
                data.push(<li key={ii}>{cc}</li>);
              });
            });

    // change here
            return data.map((d,i)=><div key={i}>{d}</div>)
// or try:
// return data.map((d,i)=><d/>)
          };
          render() {
            return (
              <div>
                {this.renderQuestions()}
                {this.renderChoices()}
              </div>
            );
          }
        }
```

Comment: I tried both of your solutions but both of them don't work

Answer (score 0):

Change your function as follows. Since you are rendering just the first question in your sample, this will render only the fist set of choices. However, you have made this problem complex by separating questions and choices into two arrays in the state.

```
renderChoices = () => {
    return this.state.choices[0].map((ch, i) => {
      return <li key={i}>{ch.choice}</li>
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
 renderChoices = () => {
          let data = [];
          if (this.state.choices.length > 0) {
              var Answer = this.state.choices[0]
              Answer.map((ch, i) => {
                  data.push(ch.choice)
              });
          }
          return data;
      };
```